# How to fix creating featherlight div-s right away after body selector?

Tags: javascript, featherlight.js

We need to install **Google Tag manager** code right away after `<body>` and before any others tags (to avoid warnings from google tag assistant).
But **featherlight** creates it own `<div class="fm-outer">`.
How can we add code between `<body>` and `<div class="fm-outer">`?
Thanks.

```html
<body>
  
...... we need this place
  
  <div class="fm-outer"> ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create some `<div class='put-featherlight-here'>` where it suits you and specify `'.put-featherlight-here'` as the `root` option.

Hopefully I understood you answer.

If not, provide a jsfiddle.